# generate multiple sums from the same query

Tags: mysql, join, inner-join, right-join

I have a table like this:

```
id   person_id  total amount    date_time
1    101        2000            2001-12-10
2    102        1000            2001-12-10
3    102        3000            2001-12-10
4    102        2000            2001-12-10
5    103        1000            2001-12-11
6    101        1000            2001-12-11
7    102        3000            2001-12-11
8    102        4000            2001-12-11
9    102        4000            2001-12-11
```

I want the output to be like the one below for the date 2001-12-11

```
person_101   person_102   person_103
1000         11000         1000
```

I've tried using the `SUM()` function but am stuck with the `WHERE` and `JOIN` clauses.
How do I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT
  SUM(CASE WHEN person_id = 101 THEN total_amount ELSE 0 END) as person_101,
  SUM(CASE WHEN person_id = 102 THEN total_amount ELSE 0 END) as person_102,
  SUM(CASE WHEN person_id = 103 THEN total_amount ELSE 0 END) as person_103
FROM
  my_table
WHERE
  date_time ='2001-12-11'
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pivot the data, unfortunately this is not dynamic in `mysql`, try this:

```
SELECT
    SUM(IF(person_id = 101,total_amount,0)) as person_101,
    SUM(IF(person_id = 102,total_amount,0)) as person_102,
    SUM(IF(person_id = 103,total_amount,0)) as person_103
FROM
    my_table
WHERE
    date_time = '2001-12-11'
```

Also you can do this pivot split by date , you just need to have it in the field list and group by it :

```
SELECT
    date_time,
    SUM(IF(person_id = 101,total_amount,0)) as person_101,
    SUM(IF(person_id = 102,total_amount,0)) as person_102,
    SUM(IF(person_id = 103,total_amount,0)) as person_103
FROM
    my_table
GROUP BY
    date_time
```

Comment: Thanks this works....
But what if the number of person increases dynamically i.e. 104, 105 and so on...
Can we increase the number of columns returned by the query dynamically...